# Keyboard shortcut to select favorite folder in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a keyboard shortcut to access favorite folders in Outlook 2010?

**Background:** I use IMAP (gmail) with Outlook that's why my "main" Inbox is not and can not be the default .pst (the option is greyed out).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with windows shortcuts, rather than within outlook:

1. Create a new shortcut on your desktop (for now) and make the target outlook.exe (save)
2. Right-click the shortcut and select properties, and add the following switches to the target command line: `/recycle /select "outlook:Inbox"`, replacing Inbox with the folder you want to open.
3. In the Shortcut Key, choose the shortcut for this folder

Now whenever you hit the shortcut, you'll be taken to Outlook at the folder chosen.

Comment: Expanding on Pauls answer... Within Windows 7 you could then pin the created shortcut to your taskbar, then use `Windows Key+number` to run it, aswell as having '1 click button' viewable whatever you have open :)